# Issue when calling function from other Python file

Tags: python, function-call

I'd like help to resolve an issue I run into when I import and try to use a function that is stored in another python file. I am pretty sure it's a basic mistake I am making, and in the other Stackoverflow posts I haven't found anything similar.

The function that I have imported contains some numpy functionality. After importing it, when I call it I get the following error:
"NameError: name 'np' is not defined".

Python doesn't seem to know that np represents numpy. But I have imported Numpy as np in both the file that contains the functions as well in the new Jupyter notebook where I want to use the functions.
Anybody has any ideas on how to fix this?

The code of the function I am trying to import is:
def find_str_col(df): 
 
    str_col=[]

for i in range(0,df.shape[1]):
x = np.sum(df.iloc[:,i].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,str))) 
 str_col.append(x) 
 str_col = np.squeeze(np.where(np.array(str_col)>0)) 
return str_col

I tried importing the function find_str_col in two ways and both ways don't work: 
from Loan_price_utils import *

and also: from Loan_price_utils import find_str_col

If I do copy and paste the actual function in the new workbook it does work.

Comment: Please show us the code; it's terribly hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Hi AKX, adding some more information to the post, somehow I can't format the additional information in the comment nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare 'np' as an alias for numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

Otherwise 'np' remains an unknown name.

Comment: Doesn't he say he has done that in his question? In either case the OP needs to provide more info.

Comment: Hi Peter, VitaminM, indeed I have declared import numpy as np in both files. Following the request of another stackoverflow user I have added some code. Thanks for helping

Comment: Hi VitaminM, it turns out you were right. I had updated the file "Loan_price_utils" and added "import numpy as np", but  the change had not been saved. <br/> When I properly saved the change and restarted the kernel it worked fine. Thanks